# Explode list separated by tags

Tags: php, list, explode

I have a list that is separated like this:

```
<!--start-->
item 1
<!--end-->
<!--start-->
item 2
<!--end-->
```

I need to make an array with the first var is item 1 and the second item 2 and so on...

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = .... <your data>
$array = explode('<!--start-->\n', $string);
$final = array();
foreach ($array as $line) {
   $final[] = str_replace('<!--end-->\n', '', $line);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
```

That will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! If there's content before the list, it will be first in the array, how cai I get rid of it?

Comment: What is the 'echo "<pre>";' there for ?

Comment: You can search for the first occurrence `<!--start-->` and then begin there.

Comment: The `<pre>` just formats the array when print_r() outputs it. Purely visual.

Comment: @David who said something about the output being rendered inside a browser ? And, apart from that, this is invalid html :-)

Comment: Every time I deal with an array, I always check it in a browser, and it makes it easier when you have it formatted nicely with `<pre>` :P

Comment: You need to use `preg_split()` the same way I used explode, and then you would just use the whole document and only look for text inside the `<!--start-->` and `<!--end-->` tags. However, I'm TERRIBLE at regex. Someone please help with the regex to get the info between those to tags.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the preg_split() function.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Why ? This site is to offer help on how to find a solution. It is not about making someones elses homework.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I completely agree with arkascha, its a good starting place for someone who clearly hasnt done much research on the topic beforehand.  Its a perfectly valid answer and one that will actually make the OP learn rather than copy/paste as per many answers on here.

Comment: @Jon Taylor: It's called a *hint*. And regarding your idealistic teach-2-fish viewpoint: This answer probably just confused him and he haven't learnt a thing.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what utter utter rubbish.  Why would telling him where to start looking confuse him?  I know very well that when I teach students they are far more grateful for giving them hints in the right direction than full blown answers, granted its generally for the ones that are interested in the subject, but to be quite honest I have no interest in trying to explain anything to someone who isnt willing to put in a bit of work themselves.

Comment: feel free to ask the OP. also, check the last comment on @David's answer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I expect the OP is pretty capable of deciding himself what to do with a hint. Claiming he is not able to understand something is pretty ignorant. You might want to reconsider that statement.

Comment: I'm guessing you are someone that needs every detail explaining to you are you @KarolyHorvath, I will make sure that I describe in full detail just for you next time you have a question.  It is a shame that you feel the OP is incapable of typing **preg_split() function** into google and learning about it, in order to figure a solution by himself.

Comment: @Dor Aharonson: could you come up with a solution based on this "hint" ?

Comment: @all sorry, could we just stop this stupid discussion. this certainly confuses and annoys everyone around, including the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is in `$input`:

```
// remove the start tag and add a newline at the end
$input = str_replace("<!--start-->\n", "", $input . "\n");

// break the list into an array (the last item will be an empty string)
$output = explode("\n<!--end-->\n", $input);

// remove the empty item at the end
unset($output[count($output) - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

```
$str = "<!--start-->
item 1
<!--end-->
<!--start-->
item 2
<!--end-->";

$in = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

function filter($ell) {
    if (strpos($ell, '<!--') !== 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$arr = array_filter($in, 'filter');

var_dump($arr);
```